# Advancing array pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a C array as follows:

```
 unsigned long arr[10];
```

On my machine, `unsigned long` is 8 bytes. I have a situation where I write 4 bytes using arr[0], and then need to find the address of the next byte in the array.

```
 void * ptr = arr[0] + (sizeof(unsigned long) / 2);
```

Will the above work ?

Comment: it will work on your machine, but is undefined behavior/won't work on other systems. Sizes of types are implementation dependant in c.

Comment: Are you trying to always advance the pointer by 4 bytes, or are you trying to always advance by half the size of an unsigned long?

Comment: By half the size of unsigned long

Comment: @Jake, Then the answer I wrote should do what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it will not. You should cast to `char*` first and then do the pointer arithmetic.

```
 void * ptr = ((char*) &arr[0]) + (sizeof(unsigned long) / 2);
```

Comment: It seems like the OP wants to advance by half the size of an `unsigned long`. You should do `sizeof(unsigned long) / 2` to account for cases where `sizeof(unsigned long)` is not 8 bytes.